# Javascript Module design pattern in polymer 2.0

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, polymer, code-reuse, polymer-2.x

A question coming from someone who has no background in polymer 1.0/2.0. There is this huge project currently being held and I've gotten used to using module design pattern for managing code. However in polymer 2.0, we have class based style. Sorry to sound dumb, but is it possible to implement module design pattern in polymer 2.0, or even OOP design pattern? if you have any resources, please direct me there.

## Typical skeleton in polymer 2.0

```js
class MyApp extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() {
    return 'my-app';
  }
  ready() {
    super.ready();
  }
}
```

How can we make the above in to module design pattern style?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to use module pattern when Polymer recommends/provides a class based OOP design pattern? May be you could try something with the legacy way of creating Polymer elements ( https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#legacy-element ) but I would recommend using the class based pattern.

Comment: @vsr I also come from java background and i know how good OOP is, but I never thought polymer recommended that. Is there any where I can see how they manage code using OOP based?